# UIImage from a URL (google maps)

Tags: ios, google-maps, uiimage

Hi I'm trying to get an image from maps.googleapis.com. Below is my code for some reason my URL keeps coming back as Nil. Am i doing something wrong?

```
NString *imageSourceString = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?  markers=%2212547%20Hardy%20St,Overland%20Park,Kansas%22&zoom=14&size=576x640&maptype=hybrid& sensor=false";

UIImage* finalBitmap = [UIImage imageNamed:imageSourceString];

if( nil == finalBitmap )
{
    // Next, try resolving the image using the string as the file name
    finalBitmap = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageSourceString];

    if( nil == finalBitmap )
    {
        // Next, try resolving the string as a URL.

        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageSourceString];
        if( nil != url ) //url is nil at this point
        {
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            if( nil != data )
            {
                finalBitmap = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
            else
            {
                finalBitmap = nil;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            finalBitmap = nil;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to have those spaces in your `imageSourceString`?

Answer (score 2):

That can't be real code, it wouldn't even compile.  Paste the real thing.

First, it's NSString, not NString.

Second, imageWithContentsOfFile on imageSourceString is going to fail because you gave it a URL, not a filename.  You could give it a file URL but that's not what's happening here.

Third, don't use dataWithContentsOfURL in a real app - it will freeze the UI and possibly crash the app if the server on the other end is too slow.  Use asynchronous networking.  There's an excellent series of WWDC videos on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

This works great:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.yoururl.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[imageData release];
```

Your mistake is that

```
UIImage* finalBitmap = [UIImage imageNamed:imageSourceString];
```

can't get image from remote URL, so this

```
if( nil == finalBitmap )
```

will get always nil.

Check also if server return image properly.